# objects classification, mutually related features

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Looking for some inspirations on how to address the following problem:

- there is a collection of multiple *worlds*,
- each *world* has a collection of *objects*,
- a single *object*, or a *group* of *objects*, may have a maximum of one *category* assigned,
- some *categories* are mutually related - i.e., the fact that *object1* in *group1* belongs to *categoryA*, increases a chance that some other group containing the same *object1* belongs to *categoryB*

Having a dataset with multiple worlds fully described - the target is to take a completely new world and correctly categorize the objects and groups.

---

I would appreciate some ideas on how to address it.

My approach was to write classifiers that learn different characteristics of *objects* and *groups* based on the learning data, and then assign scores (a number between 0 and 1) to different combinations of *objects* in the unknown *world*. The problem I'm facing though is how to provide the final response. With like 20 classifiers and each assigning scores to multiple groups, it's difficult to say. For example, sometimes multiple classifiers return scores with very small values, that sum up to a big number, and that shades the fact that one very rare classifier returned 1.